# MockMVC perform post test to async service

Tags: spring-mvc, asynchronous, mocking, async-await, mockito

I need to test a controller which calls an asynchronous service.

**CONTROLLER CODE**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Result> massiveImport(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        service.asyncMethod(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Result(e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(new Result(saveContact.toString()), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**SERVICE CODE**

```
@Async
public Future<Integer> asyncMethod(HttpServletRequest request) throws IllegalFieldValueException, Exception {
    ...
    return new AsyncResult<>(value);
}
```

**TEST CODE**

```
MvcResult result = getMvc().perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/path/")
                           .header("X-Auth-Token", accessToken)
                           .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                           .andDo(print())
                           .andReturn();
```

Test is ok. But I would wait, before closing the test, to complete async service.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 15):

If you just want to wait for the async execution to be finished have look at [MvcResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MvcResult.html). You can wait for it with `getAsyncResult()`.

With your current code you are just performing the request without any assertions. So the test is not complete. For a complete test it takes the following two steps.

First perform the request:

```
MvcResult mvcResult = getMvc().perform(fileUpload("/path/")
                              .header("X-Auth-Token", accessToken)
                              .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                              .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
                              .andReturn();
```

Then start the async dispatch via [asyncDispatch](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#asyncDispatch-org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult-) and perform assertions:

```
getMvc().perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(...))
        .andExpect(content().string(...));
```

Comment: Hi, For me the `.andExpect(request().asyncStarted())` fails with assertion error. What am I missing? When i simply run my server the async Futures are working, but with mockmvc the Futures return immediately not waiting for the db calls, and just returnig an empty list.