# spring-test MockMvc kotlin DSL lacks async support?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

spring-test has added support for a MockMvc DSL which can be found documented here: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/languages.html#mockmvc-dsl

When testing a controller that returns a CompletableFuture (or any other async result type) a test using MockMvc needs to perform an asyncDispatch of the MvcResult before the body can be asserted.
This can be found on various blogs or stackoverflow questions:

- https://sdqali.in/blog/2015/11/24/testing-async-responses-using-mockmvc/
- [MockMVC perform post test to async service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42069226/mockmvc-perform-post-test-to-async-service)

The new DSL seems to lack a clean way to do this.

For example the following code is needed to do the asyncDispatch:

```
@Test
internal fun call() {
    val mvcResult = mockMvc.get("/execute") {
        accept = APPLICATION_JSON
    }.andExpect {
        request { asyncStarted() }
    }.andReturn()
    mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.value", Is.`is`("test")))
}
```

Am I missing something that would enable this or is this just not nicely supported in the DSL (yet)?

**Update:**
I tried improving this with an extension function on ResultActionsDsl.

```
fun ResultActionsDsl.asyncDispatch(mockMvc: MockMvc):ResultActionsDsl {
    val mvcResult = andReturn()
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.asyncDispatch(mvcResult))
    return this
}
```

This makes it possible to write the test as:

```
@Test
internal fun call() {
    mockMvc.get("/execute") {
        accept = APPLICATION_JSON
    }.andExpect {
        request {
            asyncStarted()
        }
    }
    .asyncDispatch(mockMvc)
    .andExpect {
        status { isOk }
        jsonPath("$.value") { value("test") }
    }
}
```

I still feel like this would be supported out of the box by the DSL.

Answer (score 5):

This will be supported as of Spring Framework 5.2.2 and Spring Boot 2.2.2 with the following syntax:

```kotlin
mockMvc.get("/async").asyncDispatch().andExpect {
    status { isOk }
}
```

See [related issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23758) for more details.